# Goku SSJ Berserker in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: japanese-language, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

According to this video (in spanish) [Goku SSJ Berserker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8lStbgNaDo) a magazine has showed a capture of a Dragon Ball Heroes card and it states Goku is going to achieve the super saiyan berserker form. Is this true? Can anyone read the japanese text showed in the video and/or the magazine and say if this is true?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read the japanese text but it appeared in the manga already

[image]